# How to set accessible field to true for translation in Cakephp 4?

Tags: php, cakephp-4.x

I have an entity `File` that is accessible only on its field `legend`:

```
class File extends Entity
{
    use TranslateTrait;

    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => false,
        'legend' => true
    ];
}
```

I use the TranslateBehavior so that I'm able to translate the field `legend`

```
class FilesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Translate', ['fields' => ['legend']]);
    }
}
```

But the translation is not saved for this field. (Only the main language for `legend` is saved).

When I set `$_accessible` to `'*' => true`, the translations of `legend` are well saved.

**How (and Where) can I tell to Cakephp to set the field `legend` accessible for translation ?** (and keep `$_accessible` in my File Entity to `'*' => false, 'legend' => true`)

Comment: Did you follow **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html#saving-multiple-translations**?

Comment: @ndm Yes I did, but in my case file legends are saved using associated data inputs https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data and I don't know where to change "accessible" for translated `legend` field. **In fact I would love that my File Entity could understand that `legend` field has to be accessible whatever the language...**

Comment: @ndm Incidentally, I find strange that my Entity doesn't automatically understand that the field `legend` has to be accessible also for translations when I set `'legend' => true`. Is there a way to add code in my Entity to tell it ?

Comment: You don't necessarily want to allow mass assignment of translations by default, hence this is not a feature that would be enabled out of the box. Have you tried adding `_translations` to your accessible field as mentioned in the linked docs? If so, what exactly happened?

Comment: @ndm Oh thank you ! It works just adding `'_translations' => true`to `$_accessible` !... I haven't noticed that line in the documentation of TranslateBehavior... Thanks again !